# CSS Cod5 Rain username? Can it be coded and if so how would I go about it

Tags: css, xenforo

So i'm new to using css and im currently working on a forum thats using xenforo. However I thought it'd be neat to see this effect in place of the admins or moderators usernames.

If you guys could help me out or give me some info on how to go about it that'd be great!

Heres a Video of what I mean if you don't know:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdL9iDQs3t8

Also, I'm trying to do this all in css only for the "User Name CSS" field on xenforo. I'll keep tryig to figure it out but thanks if you can help!

Comment: I don't think that's possible with *soley* CSS. You'll need CSS to pretty it up though.

Comment: Use CSS and JS you can see example here https://rainbowcoding.com/2011/12/02/how-to-create-rainbow-text-in-html-css-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to the text in that video, would be to have a rainbow gradient across the entire phrase, not a different colour per letter.

I have created an example here:

```css
.rainbow_text {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange , yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

.rainbow_text.animated {
      animation: rainbow_animation 5s ease-in-out infinite;
      background-size: 400%;
}

@keyframes rainbow_animation {
    0%, 100% {
        background-position: 0
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 100%
    }
}
```

```html
  <h1 class='rainbow_text'>Austen Holland</h1>
  <br>
  <h1 class='rainbow_text animated'>Austen Holland Animated</h1>
```

There are two pieces of CSS that make this possible. `background-clip` / `-webkit-background-clip:` and `color`.

When the `background-clip` property is set to `text`, the background is painted within (clipped to) the foreground text.

When the `color` property is set to `transparent`, the text is.. well.. transparent. That allows the gradient from the background to show through!

There a few catches here though, and that's [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Browser_compatibility) with `background-clip: text;`!
Internet explorer does not support it at all, and chrome, opera, safari, android all require the `-webkit-` vendor prefix. Browsers like edge and firefox support it without the prefix.

[image: Browser compatibility chart]